# Mongoose discriminators and required/unique fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Does anyone know how Mongoose handles required/unique fields in Discriminator models?

For example, let's say we have base `User` model:

```
{
  name: { type: String },
  email: { type: String }
}
```

And we have 2 discriminator models created from `User`, let's say Authors and Moderators,

```
// Author
{
  phone: { type: String, required: true }
}
```

```
// Moderator
{
  reviews: { type: Array }
}
```

Since all 3 models are pointing to the same collection behind the scene, what happens when new `Moderator` is created? It is logical that error would be thrown since `Author` introduced **required** field that `Moderator` does not have.

How is that handled? Discriminators are not properly documented at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing really to document there. `required` is a client-side validator, applied on the schema level to all instances of the class.

When you save the document it is either an Author (assuming Admin was a typo) or a Moderator. The former has an extra field with attached validator.

Mongo is a shemaless database, so unless you explicitly define schema-json on the db side, you are free to insert documents of any shape.

If you check raw documents in the database , you will notice that mongoose adds few "hidden" fields for internal use: `__v` for versioning, `__t` for discriminators. The later is used to instantiate correct model when loaded from the collection, and to use in filters when you search for specific model.

You didn't ask, but for the sake of improving documentation, more interesting things happen when you add a unique index to one of the children. The uniqueness is handled serverside, so mongoose defines a [unique partial index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/) to apply only to the documents with specific value in the discrimination field. It's quite self-explanatory in the code: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/d488b6622a4cfce5370e54a9aacadf0927713cea/lib/helpers/indexes/decorateDiscriminatorIndexOptions.js

Comment: That explain the `required`, but what about the `unique`. That can not be handled client-side, without checking in db itself, right? Yeah, I though to add indexes to the question as well. I assumed they do it with `sparse` option. I updated question and change `Admin` for `Author`. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the last paragraph explain how unique indices works? it's not sparse index but partial. Not sure how to explain it better. mongoose doesn't really add much on top of mongo functionality there.  It's literally 10 lines of code behind the link.